# How to take user to specific tabs using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

How to take user from a html page to a specific html tab page when user clicked a specific tab using Javascript?

I would like to create something like to link a specific tab from a html pages, to another html pages so that when user clicks on the link it will take them to the specific tab.

**Both of the html are separated .html file**

This is my **Home.html** page code

```
<style>
body {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.box {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.btn-success {
  margin: 200px 55px;
}

</style>

  </head>
  <body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-success">LEARN MORE 1</a>
      </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="box">
    <a href="" class="btn btn-success">LEARN MORE 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="box">
    <a href="" class="btn btn-success">LEARN MORE 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="box">
    <a href="" class="btn btn-success">LEARN MORE 4</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="box">
    <a href="" class="btn btn-success">LEARN MORE 5</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="box">
    <a href="" class="btn btn-success">LEARN MORE 6</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
    </div>
```

This is my **Service.html** tab page code

```
<div class="tab-content">
        <div id="LEARN-MORE-1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
          <h3>LEARN MORE 1</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="LEARN-MORE-2" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>LEARN MORE 2</h3>
          <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="LEARN-MORE-3" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>LEARN MORE 3</h3>
          <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="LEARN-MORE-4" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>LEARN MORE 4</h3>
          <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have no Javascript knowledge, sorry for not providing my Javascript code here. I have no idea how to create the javascript file.

How to link the html page and take user to the specific tab when using clicked the learn more button?

Something like this:

[image: this]

Your help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add the link in a href as follow

```
 <a href="page_link#desired_tab_id">
```

Answer (score 0):

If You don't have javascript knowledge , better you can use bootstarp tab concept.
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

It will handle all switching of tabs.